# Animate height change UITableView but ignore UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

Currently, I expand the height of my UITableViewCell to add a 45px bottom bar to the view. When I call `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()`, the height animates correctly, but it causes my text to appear to be re-drawn from the center of the cell to the top.

This is pretty jarring, because the text is actually in the same place after this bar is shown and it seems to be animating because a new bottom anchor for the UILabel is set. Is there any way to *just* animate the bottom bar and keep the UILabel in the same location? Attached is what is currently ocurring:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zj9u5.jpg

I have tried running it in an animation-less completion block like so:

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

which keeps the text in the same place, but does not animate the bottom bar at all (as was expected with this method). Ideally, I could achieve the same with the UILabel and not with the rest of the UITableViewCell.

Edit: Some of my AL code that is running before I do beginUpdates(). I am using a library called Anchorage which makes the AL syntax a lot easier to understand, but this is effectively making visual layout constraint language with a custom syntax

```
NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(menuHeight)
menuHeight = batch {
    menu.heightAnchor == CGFloat(45)
    menu.horizontalAnchors == contentView.horizontalAnchors
    menu.bottomAnchor == contentView.bottomAnchor
    title.bottomAnchor == menu.topAnchor - CGFloat(8)
    menu.topAnchor == title.bottomAnchor + CGFloat(8)
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code for autolayout and the code for animation because i can't figure where you are adding the 54px, what the bottom bar is, etc.

Comment: Check my edits @RakeshaShastri, also I fixed the link to be a video and not a static image

Comment: Instead of changing the height of complete cell you can change the height of that image bar from 0 to any specific number.

Comment: You need to specify only one of last 2 constraints, preferably the last one only. Also remove any other anchors that may be attached to the bottom.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri unfortunately, removing either of those still has the same animation effect. I will take another look at the bottom anchors but I believe the only one with a bottom anchor set is the menu

Comment: @shivi_shub that is what my code is currently doing, menu's height anchor is 0 and is then set to 45, which is then animated by the UITableView

Comment: Can't figure out what the problem with the gif ??  if you need the label to be centered then remove the 2 bottom constraints and implement heightForRowAt

Comment: @Sh_Khan, look at how the text seems to pop in from the top while the menu is being shown. I would like it to remain static and only animate the bottom menu with the images. heightForRowAt is not implemented because my UITableView uses AutoLayout for all heights and AutomaticRowDimension

Comment: @Sh_Khan that doesn't animate the cell.

Comment: @Sh_Khan, that is a very expensive call when only updating one cell (and it doesn't animate)

Comment: I know it's , beginUpdates always have an attached animation , can you try **UIView.animate(withDuration:1.0) { cell.layoutIfNeeded() }**

Comment: Hey. Why is the label pushed a bit more to the left when you are adding the menu?

Comment: @Rakesha Shastri the reason I need to set both bottom constraints is the UILabel is bound to the bottom of the superview and it is changed to be the bottom of the menu when the menu is displayed

Comment: textview? i thought you were using label? Why are you binding textView to the bottom when the menu is always there with a height 0 and it's just changed to height 45 when needed?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri sorry I meant the UILabel. That is a good point though, I could always just make it the menu bottom. Let me try that and I'll get back to you

Comment: it seems that you have a conflict , before you hook the bottom's constraint of the title to the menu , you have to remove the bottom to the superView or always hook the bottom of the label to the top of the menu and play only with the menu' height constant